# Howler.js syntax for detecting when sound stops playing

Tags: howler.js

I am using Howler.js to play some sounds, but I wish to understand how to interact with the playing sound from inside other functions.

Specifically, I have not seen demo code for the playing / duration methods.

Where does one get the ID and how is that to be used in a practical example with `.playing()` or `.duration()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code:

```
let sweet = new Howl({ src: ['website/assets/sweetchild.mp3'] });

let sweetid = sweet.play();
let dt = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

while (true){
    dt = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(dt);
    await sleep(500);
    if ( !sweet.playing(sweetid) ) break;
}
console.log('handle_cbTestButton_click - FINISHED');
```